# Android SSH with AWS and JuiceSSH

Tags: ssh

I am trying to use [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh!) to connect to my Amazon instance with Ubuntu and I am unable to skip the request for password, documentation says I should be using -i in the ssh command but I don't see that option in JuiceSSH

Added screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are searching for the ssh authentication using private key. That seems to be supported by JuiceSSH. Do you have the required private key on your Android device?

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the comment, yes I have the file and also it is used and accepted but despite this it keeps asking me for password

Answer (score 1):

This was primarily my own mistake and I am leaving it here only for future visitors who may face the same issue.

I was using a wrong pem file and since the issue was not highlighted as "wrong pem" but as it needed password I was confused.